# Simple text editor without autocomplete

Tags: python, autocomplete, editor

I am teaching programming to first year students in university. This year we will transition from Java to Python, and I am looking for a suitable text editor to deploy on our in-house server. Preferably the text editor should not offer any autocomplete functionality out of the box. I know this is a controversial topic, but my institute has concluded that autocomplete should be kept out, at least for the first semester, to help students get used to typing the standard print, open, etc. sentences.

The text editor should preferably be open source and support Linux, OSX and Windows. I have good experience with Atom, but this editor autocompletes out-of-the-box, and disabling this feature server-wide has proven difficult. If anyone knows how to do this with init/config scripts, any help would be very welcome. Otherwise, suggestions of other text editors would also be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is there really out-of-the-box Python autocomplete feature in Atom? In my installation there is none. I got the portable 1.14.3 version

Comment: Please do check the [help/on-topic]; asking for tool recommendations is off-topic here. I've duped you to the (closed) canonical Python IDE post, we can't do more.

Comment: Should there still be syntax-highlighing? How about simple text- or console-based (like e.g. `nano`)?